# call definite folder name and value in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, directory

I want to write function that will copy structure and content of one root folder to another one (that already contains most of files in the initial folder and function must compare files and directories and copy if it is not exists in destination folder). Name of folders are the dict.values().

```
def copy_tran(reg_dir):

    z_folders = os.listdir(reg_dir)
    png_folder = r'C:\Users\tei\Desktop\temp'
    png_subfolders = os.listdir(png_folder)
    for dir in z_folders:
        for pngdir in png_subfolders:
            path_dir2 = os.path.join(png_folder, pngdir) 
            path_dir = os.path.join(reg_dir, dir)
            transp_basename = os.path.basename(path_dir)[4:] 
            png_basename = os.path.basename(path_dir2)[4:] 
            if transp_basename == png_basename:
                for region in dict.values():
                    if not os.path.exists(png_folder + '\\' + 'reg_' + ('%s' % (region))):
                        os.mkdir(png_folder + '\\' + 'reg_' + ('%s' % (region)))
                    list_zooms = ['8', '9', '10', '11']                   
                    for zoom in list_zooms:
                        if not os.path.exists(png_folder + '\\' + 'reg_' + ('%s' % (region)) + '\\' + (
                                    '%s' % (zoom))):
                            os.mkdir(png_folder + '\\' + 'reg_' + ('%s' % (region)) + '\\' + ('%s' % (zoom)))
                        x_path = os.path.join(path_dir, zoom)
                        list_x = os.listdir(x_path)
                        for y in list_x:
                            y_path = os.path.join(x_path, y)
                            if not os.path.exists(png_folder + '\\' + 'reg_' + ('%s' % (region)) + '\\' + (
                                '%s' % (zoom)) + '\\' + y):
                                os.mkdir(png_folder + '\\' + 'reg_' + ('%s' % (region)) + '\\' + ('%s' % (zoom)) + '\\' + y)
```

[My code (image) is here (debug)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzFAb.png)

The problem is that when comparing folder's names, python takes random (as I see) folder in root folder (reg_CENTRSIB_NORTH) although in list (2nd line) this is the second element. So, function creates wrong folders (in destination folder reg_CENTER function create subfolders from folder reg_CENTRSIB_NORTH). 
What way I need to rewrite my code so that it calls folders of the same name (that are the dict.values())? I'm puzzled, any ideas?

Comment: how about using `shutil.copy` or `shutil.copytree`?

Comment: @DanielSanchez, https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html : shutil.copytree recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src. The destination directory, named by dst, must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent directories. But my directories exists, I need to compare them and copy missing folders and files

Comment: just scan the directories, filter wich of them does not exist and copy the remaining ones. your code its a bit messy

Comment: Check out pathlib[1] and f-strings[2]. [1: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html ] [2: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple solution to your problem based on `shutil.copy2`

```
def copydir(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            copydir(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:
                shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

This is a recursive implementation:

1. Check if the destination folder exists, if not create it
2. Loop over every element of the source folder
3. If is a folder call the function on it and GOTO 1
4. If is a file check if it exists and if it is modified: based on this copy it

This should help you jsut copy what does not esist or has been modified